# Compare multiple string between them according to different conditions

Tags: c#

is it possible to compare several strings between them according to different conditions ?

I have 4 strings to compare between them:

```
If the four are the same => one condition
(example : A,A,A,A)

If only one different value and the rest null => a condition
(example : A, A, null, A or A, null, null, null )

If there are at least two different strings other than null => another condition
(example : A,B,A,A or A,B,Null, Null)
```

do you know how I can do it, in a clean way, without making an "if" for each possible combination?

Comment: `listOfStrings.Where(x => x != null).Distinct().Count()` will tell you how many different non-null strings you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the strings in a collection and start the LINQ engine :)

> If the four are the same => one condition (example : A,A,A,A)

```
bool allSame = !strings.Distinct().Skip(1).Any(); // or Distinct().Count() == 1
```

> If only one different value and the rest null

```
bool oneNonNull = strings.Count(s => s != null).Count() == 1;
```

> If there are at least two different strings other than null

```
bool twoNonNull = strings.Where(s => s != null).Take(2).Count() == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely don't want to use `if` statements, you could use delegates with anonymous functions like so:

```
public void CompareStrings(List<string> stringsToCompare) {
            
    Func<List<string>, bool> allSame = delegate (List<string> input)
    {
        return input.Distinct().Count() == stringsToCompare.Count;
    };

    Func<List<string>, bool> oneDifferent = delegate (List<string> input)
    {
        return input.Distinct().Count() == stringsToCompare.Count - 1;
    };

    Func<List<string>, bool> twoDifferent = delegate (List<string> input)
    {
        return input.Distinct().Count() == stringsToCompare.Count - 2;
    };

    Console.WriteLine(allSame);
    Console.WriteLine(oneDifferent);
    Console.WriteLine(twoDifferent); 
}
```